# Kind of variable

Tags: python

```
class Person:
   pid = 142
   def __init__(self, pid):
        self.pid = pid
        pid = 142
        
myPerson = Person(142)
print(myPerson.pid)
```

The latest expression (myPerson.pid) is instance variable or local ?

Comment: You could use different values to find out. 142, 143 and 144 for example.

Answer (score 3):

The print will be the value used when you create an instance of Person.

```py
class Person:
    pid = 1
    # Class attribute, shared with all instances if not redefined

    def __init__(self, pid):
        print(self.pid)  # 1, because self.pid is Person.pid

        # You redefine self.pid
        self.pid = pid  # self.pid is not Person.pid

        # This is local to the function
        pid = 2  # So this line is useless
        print(self.pid, pid)  # 3 2


myPerson = Person(3)
print(myPerson.pid)  # 3
```